# c# RichTextBox control within DataGridView cell changes not persisting

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, richtextbox

I've created a DataGridView that has the column type of RichTextBox control. Using the code from here [RichTextBox Cell in a DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31823/RichTextBox-Cell-in-a-DataGridView)

But when i edit the DataGridViewCell as shown below. It doesn't work the way i want.

```
//Adding the datagridview column and two rows.

DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn richTextColumn = new DataGridViewRichTextBoxColumn();
richtextcolumn.Name = "blah";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(richTextColumn);
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("one two three four");
this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add("five six seven eight");

//Edit cell

DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells["blah"];
dataGridView1.CurrentCell = cell;
dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);
RichTextBox temp = dataGridView1.EditingControl as RichTextBox;

temp.SelectionStart = 3;
temp.SelectionLength = 4;
temp.SelectionBackColor = Color.Red;
dataGridView1.EndEdit();
```

Now this correctly changes the backcolor that i've selected but as soon as i leave the cell. It then changes to show all rtf information. Such as this

{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\deff0\deflang3081{\fonttbl{\f0\fnil\fcharset0 Microsoft Sans Serif;}}
{\colortbl ;\red255\green0\blue0;}
\viewkind4\uc1\pard\f0\fs17 five \highlight1 six\highlight0  seven eight\par
}

It seems to me that it is no longer hosting the RichTextBox control after cell edit has finished. How do i persist these changes.